# Handling multiple regex matches in Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, regular-expressions

Given this string:

```
SET @text = "<a href=""https://salesforce.stackexchange.com""target=""_blank"">Salesforce</a>
<a href=""https://stackoverflow.com"" target=""_blank"">Everything else</a>"
```

And this function:

```
SET @matching = '\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href="([^"]*)"'
SET @output = RegExMatch(@text, @matching, 1)
```

How can I manage to find and print an arbitrary number of matches in my string? E.g. in above example, I would like to present e.g. a rowset with each URL in each row.

Comment: First question: Why are the hrefs with two ", this is kinda wrong (or is this the challenge). Second: Is each line seperated by linefeeds or is it a string that is connected without any seperator (or only maybe </a>?

Comment: Just to give you a solution idea that came to my mind: count `</a>`s and iterate through the number of with multiple regexmatches with looping (variable i). RegExMatch(@text, @matching, @i)

Comment: The double-double-quotes, are for escaping purposes, as per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm

Comment: Personally i wouldnt write it that way you did. I would use: `Set @text = '<a href="https://salesforce.stackexchange.com" target="_blank"> ... '` i would nearly think that your code is wrong ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a pretty solution, but here's what I use:

```
%%[
SET @text = "<a href=""https://salesforce.stackexchange.com""target=""_blank"">Salesforce</a><a href=""https://stackoverflow.com"" target=""_blank"">Everything else</a><a href=""https://google.com"" target=""_blank"">Search</a>"
SET @href = BuildRowsetFromString(@text, 'href="')
for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@href) do
SET @endhref = BuildRowsetFromString(Field(Row(@href, @i),1), '"')
OutputLine(Concat(Field(Row(@endhref, 1),1),"<br>"))
next @i
]%%
```

> **Output:**
>  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com
>  https://stackoverflow.com
>  https://google.com